# Xamarin Error XA0009 - Format of Executable or Library is invalid

Tags: xamarin.android

I am struggling to make an Android App, but it always seems to end in this particular failure:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Exception while loading assemblies: Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA0009: Error while loading assembly: bin/Debug/(projectname).dll ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
  at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage () [0x0002d] in <1b827dd2cbec4ef6829dffcefdcd3b01>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage (Mono.Disposable`1[T] stream, System.String file_name) [0x0000a] in <1b827dd2cbec4ef6829dffcefdcd3b01>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (Mono.Disposable`1[T] stream, System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00007] in <1b827dd2cbec4ef6829dffcefdcd3b01>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00073] in <1b827dd2cbec4ef6829dffcefdcd3b01>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error (System.Int32 code, System.Exception innerException, System.String message, System.Object[] args) [0x0000a] in :0 
  at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Load (System.String fileName) [0x00045] in <9ca47d05131d4b8c85910dacd818f0c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00123] in <3f37ea95794e430e91f10accab4cf241>:0  ((projectname))

I am wondering what on earth might be causing the error, as I have tried multiple solutions to avoid the error and it often turns up in such random ways.

Last time I got the error it occurred as follows:

I had a project with only two Activity-files and two Layout files.

I created a gridview in the other layout and tested it on the Android emulator -> all was working well.

I resized the gridview and tested the app with the emulator -> error mentioned above occurred.

I deleted the solution, restored a manual backup saved in an other location, and tested it -> it was working.

I repeated the procedure with the gridview -> error occurred.

Now, as I deleted the project and tried to restore the backup again, even the backup did not work anymore. I tried to build it, then clean it and build but every attempt to build it resulted now as an error.

I seem to get mystic errors from time to time ( like Emulator image stopped working after all I did was just add a button with the designer) but every time troubleshooting eventually comes down to this error and I have to scrap the project. I have been working with Xamarin now 18 hours this weekend and 4 hours have been coding and the rest trying to fix the never-ending errors.

I am using MacBook Pro and have tried running the solution from the default directory and external drive.

So in a nutshell: What causes the error mentioned above and can it be fixed or at least avoided?

I tried to google ( long and hard) but could not find a solution that would be of any help.

Ps. Sorry if the post was not correct, it is my first. Would not have posted in the first place but I am desperate.

Thank you for your patience to read all the way to here.